# how to intergrate ckeditor in react native app

Tags: react-native, ckeditor

I want to use ckeditor in my react native app as text editor. Is there any proper documentation available which give any information about how to integrate ckeditor into react native app?

Answer (score 0):

To use the CKEditor in react here is the step-by-step guide:

**1**-Go to https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/.

**2**-Chose the editor type.

**3**-Select the plugins that you want to add.

**4**-Design the editor of your choice. https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/demo/

**5**-Select the default language for the editor and then download the zip file.

**6**-After downloading the zip file extract it.

**NOTE:** You can check the above steps here also: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/quick-start-other.html

**7**-After extracting copy and paste the folder inside the root of your project folder.

**Note:** You can rename the folder if you want.

The structure would look like this:

```
--ProjectName

      --ckeditor

      --node_modules

      --src

      --package.json

      --packagelock.json
```

**8**-Now open the terminal.

**9**-If you are using npm then run the command

**Note:** Make sure you name the folder Correctly when adding the file.

```
npm add file: ./ckeditor
```

OR if you are using yarn

```
yarn add file: ./ckeditor
```

**10**-Then install the ckeditor as:

```
npm install --save  @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react
```

OR if you are using yarn

```
yarn add @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react
```

**11**-After installation use can now use the CkEditor.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Editor as ClassicEditor } from 'ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor';
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react'

export default function App() {

return(

   <div>
    <CKEditor
            editor={ ClassicEditor }
            data="<p>Hello from CKEditor</p>"
            onReady={ editor => {
                 // You can store the "editor" and use it when desired.
                 console.log( 'Editor is ready to use!', editor );
             } }
            onChange={ ( event, editor ) => {
                 const data = editor.getData();
                 console.log( { event, editor, data } );
                    } }
            onBlur={ ( event, editor ) => {
                  console.log( 'Blur.', editor );
                    } }
            onFocus={ ( event, editor ) => {
                   console.log( 'Focus.', editor );
            } }
                
          />
   </div>
 )
}
```

**ERRORS:** This is the common error `Error: this.props.editor.create is not a function` .

But it's caused when you do this:   `import { Editor } from 'ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor';` and used as `editor={ Editor }`
inside the ckeditor component.

So make sure to write the code carefully as:

`import { Editor as ClassicEditor } from 'ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor';` and use it inside the component as `editor={ ClassicEditor }`

If you get any issues like duplicated-module make sure that you correctly installed the ckeditor.

Happy Coding and have a good day❤️.